# How does Spring Security Filter Work With Custom Authentication and How To Combine It with Servlet Filter?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

So I have a question regarding Spring Security. So I want to check authentication using custom header which then I want to check the token given in the custom header to redis value and set the data object as  credentials at custom implementation of abstract authentication token. 
I have already followed the tutorial in this web: https://shout.setfive.com/2015/11/02/spring-boot-authentication-with-custom-http-header/, but I can't update the authentication interface in SecurityContextHolder.getContext() (I set the credentials in my implementation of Authentication Interface, but when I get it in the service, the credentials is null).

I also found other problems, I actually want to order the filter like this:

```
ExceptionHandlerFilter (to catch exception error in the filter) -> Other filter or CustomWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.
```

But when the url matches the antMatcher, I found that ExceptionHandlerFilter was skipped by the application.

I was so confused by this and could not find better tutorial in implementing custom authentication using Spring Security. So I want to ask whether you guys can tell me how Spring Security works and how to combine it with Filter?

Here is my first filter to catch exception

```
@Component
@Order(0)
public class ExceptionHandlerFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private JaminExceptionHandler exceptionHandler;
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Autowired
    public ExceptionHandlerFilter(JaminExceptionHandler exceptionHandler) {
        this.exceptionHandler = exceptionHandler;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
                                    HttpServletResponse response,
                                    FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        } catch (Throwable exception) {
            ResponseEntity<?> responseEntity = this.exceptionHandler.handleException(exception, request);

            response.setStatus(responseEntity.getStatusCode().value());
            response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            response.getWriter().write(this.objectMapper.writeValueAsString(responseEntity.getBody()));
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my Auth Filter

```
@Component
public class AuthFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
                                    HttpServletResponse response,
                                    FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String token = request.getHeader("J-Auth");

        if (token != null) {
            Authentication auth = new JaminAuthenticationToken(token);
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        } else {
            throw new JaminException("Not authorized", JaminExceptionType.NOT_AUTHORIZED, HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
        }
    }
}
```

Authentication Provider

```
@Component
public class JaminAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    private RedisTemplate<String, String> authRedis;

    private ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Autowired
    public JaminAuthenticationProvider(@Qualifier("authRedis") RedisTemplate<String, String> authRedis) {
        this.authRedis = authRedis;
    }

    private UserDTO getUserDTO(String token) throws IOException {
        String userData = this.authRedis.opsForValue().get(token);

        if (userData == null) {
            throw new JaminException("Not authorized", JaminExceptionType.NOT_AUTHORIZED, HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
        }

        return this.objectMapper.readValue(userData, UserDTO.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        JaminAuthenticationToken auth = (JaminAuthenticationToken) authentication;

        try {
            UserDTO userDTO = this.getUserDTO(auth.getToken());
            auth.setCredentials(userDTO);

            return auth;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        throw new JaminException("Not authorized", JaminExceptionType.NOT_AUTHORIZED, HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return JaminAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication);
    }
}
```

WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Order(1)
public class JaminSecurityAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private JaminAuthenticationProvider jaminAuthenticationProvider;

    private void disableDefaultSecurity(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.formLogin().disable();
        http.logout().disable();
        http.httpBasic().disable();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        this.disableDefaultSecurity(http);
        http.antMatcher("/auth/check")
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .addFilterBefore(new AuthFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
//        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(jaminAuthenticationProvider);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring Security has some "before and after" [steps](https://spring.io/guides/topicals/spring-security-architecture). There are a few Handlers that can help. I don't know your code, but if you can get your authentication ok, maybe you just have to extend a SuccessHandler and set the authentication there, like i did in my [blog project](https://gitlab.com/danilo.balarini/blogkotlin/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/br/com/dblogic/blogkotlin/security/BlogAuthenticationSuccessHandler.kt):

```
if(checkEmail(authentication)) {

    val adminRole = SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")
    val oldAuthorities = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities()
    val updateAuthorities = mutableListOf<GrantedAuthority>()
    updateAuthorities.add(adminRole)
    updateAuthorities.addAll(oldAuthorities)

    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(authentication.getPrincipal(),
                                                                                                authentication.getCredentials(),
                                                                                                updateAuthorities))
}
```

And about the filters, maybe you can find your [answer](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-registered-filters) here. I don't like using filters and interceptors, but sometimes they are really necessary.

Comment: Thanks for answering this. But I still don't understand how it actually works.. Also, I have added the example in my question.